# Java NumberFormat generates 'EUR' instead of €

Tags: java, android, currency, number-formatting

I'm developing an android app that supports multiple user languages.

In the app, I'm using java.util.NumberFormat to format currency:

```
String formatCurrency(String amount) {
    // getCurrentLocale determines the locale from the user's selected language; 
    // if the user selects de_DE as the app's language, then this method will return Locale.Germany
    final Locale locale = getCurrentLocale(); 
    final NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    return formatter.format(new BigDecimal(amount));
}
```

The testing device I'm using is a HTC G2, which has two device language options - english and spanish.

Ok, now I select the user language for my app to be 'de_DE':

```
// When my device language is english, if I call:
System.out.println(formatCurrency("1.79"));
// I got:
1.79 €

// But when I switch my device language to spanish:
System.out.println(formatCurrency("1.79"));
// I got :
1.79 EUR
```

My question here is can I get the NumberFormat to give me € in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

Why not always use the `Locale` that you want it to displayed in? Ignore the device's `Locale`.

For [`Locale.ENGLISH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ENGLISH):

```
String formatCurrency(String amount) {
    final NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return formatter.format(new BigDecimal(amount));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm ignoring the device's locale in the code, but when I switches the device's languages, it does not seem to be ignored 100% by the NumberFormat. For example, as an experiment, I wrote something like this:

Comment: What is the call to `getCurrentLocale()` doing? Doesn't sound like the user's locale is being ignored from the comment above it :).

Comment: It gets the user's selected lang and maps it to the correspondent locale. For example, 'en_US' to Locale.ENGLISH and 'fr_FR' to Locale.FRANCE @cklab

Comment: Right... so I'm saying don't use that Locale.

Comment: Urrr, I have to use that locale, so that the currency can be formatted in the right way. Like 1.79 € instead of $ 1.79 when the user selects German as the language.@cklab

Comment: Ah, I see. Well the first thing I would say is I hope you're aware that conversion between currencies might require a bit more than a formatter and a locale! Furthermore, I've generally experienced this behavior when the `language` is incorrectly defined in the `Locale`. Can you provide the definition of `getCurrentLocale()`?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this](http://developers.sun.com/dev/gadc/technicalpublications/articles/java1.4currency.html).

Use the *[getSymbol()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency.html#getSymbol%28java.util.Locale%29)* from Currency's object to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Java but not in an Android project.
But using the `DecimalFormat` class returned the correct output.
Try code like the one below.

```
DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(amount);
```